# start css animation with javascript and show another button after 20s

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my project on bootstrap I have image animation when I click the button, the first button  collapses first div, is why I want to start the animation picture on the 10s delay. 20s after button1 hide and show the second button.

Part of image is hidden behind div and animation pull image to left side and show whole image.

[quick sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvsvT.jpg)

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  background: #00C8FF;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.6em;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  background-color: #00C8FF;
  padding: 1em;
  color: #002240;
  margin-top: 0;
}

#ukryty {
  height: 180px;
}

#ukryty,
#kluska_image {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #00C8FF;
}

#kluska_image {
  left: 430px;
  top: 55px;
  align-content: center;
  animation: kluska_image 5s;
  -moz-animation: kluska_image 5s;
  /* Firefox */
  -webkit-animation: kluska_image 5s;
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes kluska_image {
  from {
    left: 430px;
  }
  to {
    left: 80px;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes kluska_image {
  from {
    left: 430px;
  }
  to {
    left: 80px;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes kluska_image {
  from {
    left: 430px;
  }
  to {
    left: 80px;
  }
}

#pusty {
  width: auto;
  min-height: 150px;
}

.col-xs-offset-right-9 {
  margin-right: 75%;
}

#info {
  background-color: #222;
  padding: 10px 50px 10px 50px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  animation: blink 1s ease-in-out infinite;
  -webkit-animation: blink 1s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
  50% {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes blink {
  50% {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
  }
}

.button {
  -webkit-animation: glowing 1500ms infinite;
  -moz-animation: glowing 1500ms infinite;
  -o-animation: glowing 1500ms infinite;
  animation: glowing 2500ms infinite;
}
```

```html
<section class="container-fluid" id="section1">
  <div id="demo" class="collapse row v-center">

    <h1 class="text-center">Just One Page</h1>
    <h2 class="text-center lato">Change It To Say <b>Something</b> Unique</h2>
  </div>

</section>



<section class="container col-md-12" id="section2">
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-9" id="kluska_image">
        <img src="http://imemc.org/wp-content/uploads/dec2015/gazaflowersalray.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3" id="ukryty">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
<section class="container" id="pusty"></section>
<div class="container">
  <div class="text-right" id="klikacz">

    <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo" id="info" type="btn btn-danger" class="button text-center" onclick="#"><span>click me!</span>
    </button>
  </div>

</div>
```